# Open failed "Error Opening Feature Class"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile

when I try to open a shapefile in arcmap, I get the following error:

"Error Opening Feature Class"

The repair geometry tool did not work. Would someone be able to assist me in fixing this shapefile?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Based on the little sync symbols, I'd guess that these files are on a shared file service (such as DropBox or OneDrive).  Sync services are not a good place to store database files, such as Shapefiles.  They can easily become corrupted that way.  I also notice that all the files a zero size ("0 KB").  This means that all the files are completely empty.  Make sure that all the files are fully downloaded (from the 'net), then copy them somewhere safer and run them from there.

Comment: I downloaded these shapefiles from an email, but I still can't open them on other drives. I guess ArcMap should open these even though they are empty

Comment: No.  A shapefile wilth all files zero-sized is an unreadable, corrupted shapefile.

Comment: PS.  If you create an empty shapefile, and then look at the individual component files, you will find that they are non-empty (give it a try).  So a legitimate empty shapefile is comprised of non-empty files.  A shapefile with actually empty files is not a legitimate shapefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the files that make up that Shapefile are zero-sized ("0 KB").  Therefore it is a corrupt shapefile and cannot be opened.  (Or possibly hasn't finished downloading yet?)

It also appears to be on a sync-service (eg, DropBox, OneDrive).  This is bad practice for database files, or any files where changes must be atomic across the entire set of files.  Very easy for databases to become corrupted that way, as the databse-level file locking mechanisms won't work reliably.